# Is there a way to define snippets in the index.php or config.php file?

Tags: php, config, snippets, dynamic

I'd like to define snippets dynamically in the index.php file.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't set up Snippets, but you can set up Global Variables in your config.php file.

Below is a code example from this blog post titled [**ExpressionEngine config.php**](http://pilotmade.com/blog/expressionengine-config-php).

```
$default_global_vars = array(

    // Tag parameters - Short hand tag params
    'global:disable_default'   => 'disable="categories|pagination|member_data"',
    'global:disable_all'       => 'disable="categories|custom_fields|member_data|pagination"',
    'global:cache'             => 'cache="yes" refresh="10"',
    '-global:cache'            => '-cache="yes" refresh="10"', // disable by adding a '-' to the front of the global

    // Date and time - Short hand date and time
    'global:date_time'          => '%g:%i %a',
    'global:date_short'         => '%F %d, %Y',
    'global:date_full'          => '%F %d %Y, %g:%i %a',
    'global:isipad'             => (bool) strpos($user_agent,'iPad'),
    'global:isiphone'           => (bool) strpos($user_agent,'iPhone')

);

// Make this global so we can add some of the config variables here
global $assign_to_config;

if(!isset($assign_to_config['global_vars'])) {
    $assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array();
}

$assign_to_config['global_vars'] = array_merge($assign_to_config['global_vars'], $default_global_vars, $env_global_vars);
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know you could add a global:disable_default parameter. That's awesome. We use globals for a lot of things, but I never even looked at them for a method of setting defaults.

Comment: They're called global variables, but they look like they'd have to be parsed at the same time as snippets... I'm confused, but I'll try it. :)

Comment: To those reading this later: yes "global_vars" assigned in the config file act like snippets; they are available at the beginning of parsing, not the end.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't generate them dynamically but you can use [Snippet Sync](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/snippet-sync) or [Libraree](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/libraree) to use snippets as files and port them into other projects.

I use Libraree as part of my base install with a couple base snippets for a header and footer that I carry through projects. Using config overrides ([Focus Lab's Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config)) I set where to store the files and edit away when I set up new projects

```
// Libraree
$config['libraree_basepath'] = $base_path . '/../snippets/';
```